# Replace Content With Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/28

So it's working on jsfiddle, but not when I put it into my Wordpress header. The HTML/CSS is all good on Wordpress, but the Javascript isn't. I entered it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.tablereplace a').click(function () {
    $('.fieldsmatch').fadeOut(0);
    $('.fieldsgame1').fadeOut(0);
    $('.fieldsgame2').fadeOut(0);
    $('.fieldsgame3').fadeOut(0);
    var region = $(this).attr('data-region');
    $('#' + region).fadeIn(0);
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.fieldsgame1 {
    display:none;
}
.fieldsgame2 {
    display:none;
}
.fieldsgame3 {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Help?

Comment: What other JS files are loaded on the page? Also, is jquery loaded?

Comment: Not working is not very helpful …

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a [document ready handler](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). It works on jsfiddle without it because jsfiddle wraps your code in an `onload` handler by default (see the second drop-down on the left of the jsfiddle window under Frameworks & Extensions - you'll notice if you change that drop-down to one of the "no wrap" options your code doesn't work in the fiddle either).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tablereplace a').click(function () {
        $('.fieldsmatch').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fieldsgame1').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fieldsgame2').fadeOut(0);
        $('.fieldsgame3').fadeOut(0);
        var region = $(this).attr('data-region');
        $('#' + region).fadeIn(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IItq7eE.png This is what I'm looking at right now and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

have you included it..
http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js
that might be the problem, since i have used wordpress with javascript, works absolutely fine.